# Radial probability for orbitals

Tags: quantum-chemistry

> **Questions**
>   [image]

Question F-2:

I think question f1 requires one to relate $\mathrm{\psi^2}$ or. Probability density with radius but I am just in high school and have not learnt about Hamilton operator

Question F-1:
In second I think A should be 1s and B should be 3p

Comment: I think question f1 requires one to relate ¥^2 or. Probability density with radius but I am just in high school and have not learnt about Hamilton operator ..

Comment: In second I think A should be 1s and B should be 3p

Comment: I have suggested an edit if you feel it's an improvement you can accept it [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/13077). As for F-3 if I remember correctly there is a formula for radial nodes $\mathrm{n - l - 1}$ .As for the first question i don't know either( i'm in highschool).

Comment: Is this what they do in school? Where you are from? Randomly memorizing such things without learning about Hamiltonians and so on? "the maximum probability of finding the electron in the dxy orbital is" - I hope such a nonsensical approach to learning about nature will not discourage you.

Comment: Actually I am studying above the curriculum

Comment: Then start at the beginning. There is zero value in knowing this forumla

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st one, the maximum probablity of finding the electron occurs at the Bohr's radius,i.e. at $\ce{r=r_0}$. This can be guessed by thinking this result classically. But if you want to know the exact method, the wave function for $1s $ orbital is, $$\ce{$\psi$_{1s} = 1/$\sqrt{\pi a_0^3}$ e^{-r/a_0}}$$ So, the radial probablity distribution for the $1s$ orbital will be,$$\ce{P(r) = |$\psi$|^2 4$\pi$r^2dr}$$ which will be eqal to , $$\ce{P(r) =4/a_0^3 r^2e^{-2r/a_0}}$$ To find the value of $r$ at which $\ce{P(r)}$ is maximum , you just have to find the solution of $\ce{dP/dr =0}$. You can verify very easily that the solution is $\ce{r=r_0}$.
For the next one, the graph of **B)** is definitely for $2s$. Now, according to judgement of no. of radial nodes of $2s$ and $3p$, they  both have 1 radial node each. So, that is inconclusive. But if you would have known the wave functions, it would be easier.
The wave-function of $2s$ is $$\ce{$\psi$_{2s} = c. (2- r/a_0)e^{-r/2a_0}, where c is a constant.}$$But, wave function of $3p$ orbitals are, $$\ce{$\psi$_{3p_z} = c_1(6r/a_0 - r^2/a_0^2)e^{-r/3a_0}cos$\theta$}$$ $$\ce{$\psi$_{3p_x} = c_2(6r/a_0 - r^2/a_0^2)e^{-r/3a_0}sin$\theta$cos$\phi$}$$ $$\ce{ ($\psi$_{3p_x} is actually an additive linear combination of $\psi$(r)Y_1^1 and $\psi$(r)Y_1^{-1})}$$ and, $$\ce{$\psi$_{3p_y} = c_2(6r/a_0 - r^2/a_0^2)e^{-r/3a_0}sin$\theta$sin$\phi$}$$$$\ce{ ($\psi$_{3p_y} is actually an subtractive linear combination of $\psi$(r)Y_1^1 and $\psi$(r)Y_1^{-1})}$$So, you can see at $r= 0$, all the $3p$ orbitals have value of wavefunction (i.e. |$\psi$ |) = $0$ (simply check by putting $r$ as $0$ in all given $3p$ wave functions). But at $r =0$,$\ce{ $\psi$_{2s}}$ has non-zero finite value so, $\ce{|$\psi$|^2}$ does not vanish at origin for$ 2s$ orbitals which the given graph is showing. So, it can't be $3p$ as the value of the wave function doesn't match at origin.
 If you consider higher orbitals like $4d $ also, their wavefunction will also vanish at origin. So, the figure **B)** corresponds to $2s$.

Comment: This answer could be improved by distinguishing between the radial probability density discussed in the first question, and the probability density discussed in the second question.